# ASP.NET web forms displaying data from a table but stuck with the method behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

I did a tutorial online based on the following link:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

I had followed this tutorial without much difficulty however when I tried to do my own project, I got stuck towards the `studentGrid_GetData()`. The reason is I totally do not understand the complex code within the method and hope you  can give me a hand.

Ok I will paste the method here just in case.

```
public IQueryable<Student> studentsGrid_GetData()
{
SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
var query = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course));
return query;
}
```

I have a **Staff** table with data and I'm hoping to display just the entire table of data onto my **Staff.aspx** page.

Can you teach me how to solve this problem and what kind of materials should I be searching on?

Comment: You got the data, and what are you doing with it? Do you feed it to something like a GridView or Repeater? Search for GridView datasource.

Answer (score 0):

When you return from the method, you only have a query - not the data. By the time you actually run the query, the "db" variable is probably disposed off as it was a method variable.

You need to materialize your query i.e. run the query and get the data. You can do that by using below changes:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> studentsGrid_GetData()
{
    SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext();
    var query = db.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(e => e.Course)).ToList();
    return query;
}
```